# "Раб" и "ребенок"

Tags: этимология

Когда-то попадалась информация о том, что слова "раб" и "ребенок" имеют одно происхождение. И именно отсюда происходит выражение "рабы Божии" - то есть, речь не идет о рабстве, а словосочетание употребляется в значении "дети Божии". Правда ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раб и ребенок действительно восходят к одному корню, но это не даёт нам права считать в конкретном сочетании рабов детьми.
Исходно "раб" имело более широкое значение. Слуга, работник и даже подданный.
Вот в этих значениях - особенно в первом, "слуга" - оно и вошло в Ветхий завет. Да-да, это понятие совсем не христианский эксклюзив.

А вообще см. здесь: http://www.pravoslavie.ru/smi/36741.htm

Comment: @SergeyBailo писал: ребенок это отпыск от которого пока не т(РЕБ)уют трудиться по факту его слишком юного п(РЕБ)ывания а состоит из слова Бер зверь, а его перевёрт указывает на его противоположный смысл хотя пока столь же беспомощного как и малыши у бера и способного только громко РЕВеть аки дикий Бер.

Answer (score 1):

Слова *раб* и *ребенок* имеют общий индо-европейский корень orbhos, значение которого довольно расплывчато: 'сирота, осиротелый, маленький, слабый, беспомощный > беззащитеый сирота, готовый даже на унизительный **труд** ради куска хлеба‘ (ср. нем. Arbeit - 'работа', латин. orbus - 'лишенный, чего-либо, осиротевший').
Собственно русское слово *ребенок* происходит от *робя* (корень orb - 'слабый, беспомощный'), которое известно в формах *робяты, робенок*, созранившихся в говорах. (П.Я.Черных. Историко-этимологический словарь современного русского языка)

Answer (score 0):

изначально слово *рба, раба, арба* означало *новорожденный, ползунок, активная душа, подвижность, начавший ходить ребёнок* позже возраст увеличился до 8-13 лет - время когда ребёнка навремя отдавали в другую семью (особый элемент воспитания с несколькими формами) где им приходилось много работать. В большинстве языков *ра, рба* означает активность.

Answer (score 0):

Ревунок,требунок из у трэбы матери.,рэбя он же рева.,ревет=требит,требуе....травае=рабае..фр.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку жена первого человека вышла из ребра его, то не логично ли было назвать плоды от ребра реберными?

Answer (score -1):

Корни интересующих вас слов — в славянских языках. *Робенок*, *робяты* происходят 
от славянского *робичь*( robic), то бишь: робенок, тот, кого зробили! А робяты — те, кто робят (товарищи-мастера); ведь слово *мастер* — нерусское. А как называли мастеров по-нашему? Робяты!

Comment: @SergeyBaylo пишите ваши дополнения в виде ответа или комментария.

Comment: @SergeyBaylo писал: а вы не слыштите что ли . Робяты (роб я и ты)- просто обращение ко всей группе, имеющих равный статус, ко всем сразу. Робить это трудится, но не работать(раб(не от своей воли труд) и тать(обманщик, преступник)-значит работать это отрабатывать свои преступления. а вот роб это рабочий муж. . Как пример "хлебороб" разница между раб и роб это труд добровольный или не вольный. выходит рабы это те же каторжники.